# Rails Select Association with Model in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can i associate item with the association. Here an example and here the models

```
-Customer
-Phone
-PhoneType

Customer          Phone             PhoneType
Id                Id                Id
First             Number            Description
Last              Phone_Type_Id
Email             isViewed
Password
...
```

The relationship his has follow

```
Customer
  has_many phone
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone, allow_destroy: :true
Phone
  belongs_to :customer
  has_one :phone_type
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone, allow_destroy: :true
PhoneType
  belongs_to :phone
```

The way my form view work his has follow in
Customer#edit view
  I render a general form which consist of other fields and inside of it I have the following code

```
<%= f.fields_for :phones do |b| %>
<fieldset>
    <%= b.label :number %>
    <%= b.select :PhoneType %>  ## issues is here
    <%= b.label :isViewed %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
:phone_type
```

instead of using camelcase (PhoneType) in the form. Your association in the phone model expects a field called :phone_type so you need to fix the case.

Also, what is being rendered in your views with the way they are now? Are you getting any errors?

So you want go give the user the option to select a phone type by choose a description from the dropdown? You might try something like

```
<%= select(:phone_type, :phone_type_id, PhoneType.all, :id, :description) %>
```

Finally, you might want to take a look at the simple form gem....
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/

Comment: Well i was a step ahead, so you think if i do phone_type then the description of phone_type would show up? ( one step ahead right now my fields for doesn't show anything)

Comment: Thanks :D so would it would be associated to b?

Comment: Yes, so the user selects the description from the select box, then the PhoneType id is sent to the server as the association